# Sending array along with javascript call to the Driver class in java -rest

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I am trying to add an array of four items to a call of a driver class. My JavaScript code works like this:

```
request.open("GET","rest/ds/acceptInput?UserInput="+document.getElementById('text').value, async=true);
request.send()
```

I use this to send the user input to the driver, AND **THIS WORKS** with an annotated driver (seen below).

```
@Test
@Path("acceptInput")
@GET
@Consumes("text/plain")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String acceptInput(@QueryParam("UserInput") String input{
```

**NOW** I would like to be able to send an array (attained by user checkboxes in JavaScript) along with my call to the driver. I've tried a few ways, but what makes sense to me is this:

JavaScript code like this:

```
request.open("GET","rest/ds/acceptInput?UserInput="+document.getElementById('text').value + checked[0],checked[1],checked[2],checked[3], async=true);
request.send()
```

And the driver accepting it like this:

```
    @Test
    @Path("acceptInput")
    @GET
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String acceptInput(@QueryParam("UserInput") String input, @QueryParam("po") boolean Po, @QueryParam("cl") boolean Cl, @QueryParam("ac") boolean Ac, @QueryParam("qu") boolean Qu) {
```

But now I end up not returning ANY results. Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JavaScript code to this:

```
request.open("GET","rest/ds/acceptInput?UserInput="+document.getElementById('text').value + "&po="+ checked[0]+"&cl="+checked[1]+"&ac="+checked[2]+"&qu="+checked[3], true);
```

You weren't giving any parameter names to the checkbox values in your GET request.

Also, instead of `async = true` parameter shouldn't it just be `true`?

Comment: sigh. so simple. THANK YOU. this worked perfectly. (i am NOT good at javascript... i only use it to test my webservice)

Comment: not sure about the async =true vs just true thats another good question

Comment: @Jason yeah javascript isn't my favorite either (mostly beacause it's not strongly typed), but it's a necessity for web development

Comment: the annoying part is being a java developer with webservice 3rd party...